# Creating a Motion JPEG frame by frame with variable frame-rate

Tags: delphi, video, jpeg, mjpeg, mplayer

I'm analyzing a number of solutions to the problem that I have in hand: I'm receiving images from a device and I need to make a video file out of it. However, the images arrive with a somewhat random delay between them and I'm looking for the best way to encode this. I have to create this video frame by frame, and after each frame I must have a new video file with the new frame, replacing the old video file.

I was thinking of fixating the frame-rate a little "faster" than the minimum delay that I might get and just repeat the last frame until a new one arrives, but I guess that this solution is not optimal.

Also, this project is made with Delphi (no, I cannot change that) and I need means to turn these frames into a video file after each frame. I was thinking about using [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html) as an external tool, but I'm reading the documentation and still haven't found an option to make it insert a frame in an already encoded Motion JPEG video file. As my images come in as JPEG, I thought that it would be reasonable to use Motion JPEG, but not even this is certain yet. Also, I don't know if mencoder can be used as a library. It would help a lot if it did.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some media container formats that support [variable frame rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats), but I don't think MJPEG is good choice because of the storage overhead. I believe the best way would be to transcode JPEG frames to MP4 format using both I-frames and P-frames.

You can use [FFMPEG Delphi/FP header files](http://www.iversenit.dk/dev/ffmpeg-headers/) for the transcoding.

***Edit:***

The most up to date version of FFMPEG headers can be found at [GLScene repository on SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=29749). To view the files you can use [this link](http://glscene.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/glscene/branches/GLScene_1_2_0/Source/FFmpeg/)

Comment: Wow, something like this I desperately need as well. Look carefully at the version numbers of avformat-??.dll. From the link provided you get version 50 while the code specifies 52. Next you need to download swscale-0.dll which you can download from http://www.dll-file-download.com/dll-files/?classid=19&id=16612&pathid=0. I'll experiment further, if someone got it working I am interested to hear.

Comment: Actually the most up to date version that I could find which matches the latest DLLs can be found at GLScene repository on SourceForge.net. The SVN view link is: http://glscene.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/glscene/branches/GLScene_1_2_0/Source/FFmpeg/

Comment: Well, avcodec needs ctypes and that needs successive more files which I can't find on sourceforge. Something seems to be missing, any ideas?

Comment: Goto http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php then download required package. If you are not sure, download all-in-one bundle from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gtk+/2.24/gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win32.zip

Comment: I'm afraid this is not gonna work. It does not contain the required functions like cTypes, cUtils etc. I give up for now. Thanks very much for your time and advice. I'll ask the same question in a more general way.

Comment: @Arnold: I already use it without any problem. It has more than required modules, so I removed some DLLs also. ;)