# How to convert bitmaps to video?

Tags: delphi, video, bitmap, video-encoding

My application creates images from fractals and I love the feeling of 'flying' around a fractal. I once saved about 2000 bitmaps to file and created an AVI from it using Premiere. That experience is rather frustrating though I succeeded in creating a movie. That was spectacular. Of course I want to create a video from my application. I actually don't care about the niftyness of the codec, compression or whatever. I just want to have a video that I can replay on most systems.

In the past I have tried this but never succeeded. I was triggered by a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584025/creating-a-motion-jpeg-frame-by-frame-with-variable-frame-rate) recently but alas could not get FFMpeg running.

**Update**

I decided to adapt the question slightly and put a bounty for it. I have seen several solutions but the most attractive (because it's simple) seems to me TAviWrite. I tried TAviWriter but did not succeed. In procedure TAviWriter.Write; the function call around line 370

```
  AVIERR := AVISaveV(s,
//                   pchar(FileName),
               nil,                    // File handler
               nil,                    // Callback
               nStreams,               // Number of streams
               Streams,
               CompOptions);           // Compress options for VideoStream
```

does not return AVIERR_OK.

**Update 2**

The reason for above mentioned error is a wrong declaration of AVISaveV, it should be declared as AVISaveVW as TLama pointed out. The correct code for creating AVI filoes form BMP files is posted below. The original code below was [downloaded from efg](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Graphics/FileFormatsAndConversion.htm) with an example unit.

Using Delphi XE on Windows 7.

```
unit AviWriter;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                         //
//       AviWriter -- a component to create rudimentary AVI files          //
//                  by Elliott Shevin, with large pieces of code           //
//                  stolen from Anders Melander                            //
//       version 1.0. Please send comments, suggestions, and advice        //
//       to shevine@aol.com.                                               //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

interface

uses
  Windows,Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, ole2;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                            //
//                      Video for Windows                                     //
//                                                                            //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                            //
// Adapted from Thomas Schimming's VFW.PAS                                    //
// (c) 1996 Thomas Schimming, schimmin@iee1.et.tu-dresden.de                  //
// (c) 1998,99 Anders Melander                                                //
//                                                                            //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                            //
// Ripped all COM/ActiveX stuff and added some AVI stream functions.          //
//                                                                            //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Unicode version created by Arnold and TLama (2012)                         //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

type
  LONG = Longint;
  PVOID = Pointer;

const
// TAVIFileInfo dwFlag values
   AVIF_HASINDEX          = $00000010;
   AVIF_MUSTUSEINDEX      = $00000020;
   AVIF_ISINTERLEAVED     = $00000100;
   AVIF_WASCAPTUREFILE    = $00010000;
   AVIF_COPYRIGHTED       = $00020000;
   AVIF_KNOWN_FLAGS       = $00030130;

   AVIERR_UNSUPPORTED     = $80044065; // MAKE_AVIERR(101)
   AVIERR_BADFORMAT       = $80044066; // MAKE_AVIERR(102)
   AVIERR_MEMORY          = $80044067; // MAKE_AVIERR(103)
   AVIERR_INTERNAL        = $80044068; // MAKE_AVIERR(104)
   AVIERR_BADFLAGS        = $80044069; // MAKE_AVIERR(105)
   AVIERR_BADPARAM        = $8004406A; // MAKE_AVIERR(106)
   AVIERR_BADSIZE         = $8004406B; // MAKE_AVIERR(107)
   AVIERR_BADHANDLE       = $8004406C; // MAKE_AVIERR(108)
   AVIERR_FILEREAD        = $8004406D; // MAKE_AVIERR(109)
   AVIERR_FILEWRITE       = $8004406E; // MAKE_AVIERR(110)
   AVIERR_FILEOPEN        = $8004406F; // MAKE_AVIERR(111)
   AVIERR_COMPRESSOR      = $80044070; // MAKE_AVIERR(112)
   AVIERR_NOCOMPRESSOR    = $80044071; // MAKE_AVIERR(113)
   AVIERR_READONLY        = $80044072; // MAKE_AVIERR(114)
   AVIERR_NODATA          = $80044073; // MAKE_AVIERR(115)
   AVIERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL  = $80044074; // MAKE_AVIERR(116)
   AVIERR_CANTCOMPRESS    = $80044075; // MAKE_AVIERR(117)
   AVIERR_USERABORT       = $800440C6; // MAKE_AVIERR(198)
   AVIERR_ERROR           = $800440C7; // MAKE_AVIERR(199)

// TAVIStreamInfo dwFlag values
   AVISF_DISABLED         = $00000001;
   AVISF_VIDEO_PALCHANGES = $00010000;
   AVISF_KNOWN_FLAGS      = $00010001;

type
  TAVIFileInfoW = record
    dwMaxBytesPerSec,// max. transfer rate
    dwFlags,         // the ever-present flags
    dwCaps,
    dwStreams,
    dwSuggestedBufferSize,

    dwWidth,
    dwHeight,

    dwScale,
    dwRate, // dwRate / dwScale == samples/second
    dwLength,

    dwEditCount: DWORD;

    szFileType: array[0..63] of WideChar; // descriptive string for file type?
  end;
  PAVIFileInfoW = ^TAVIFileInfoW;

  TAVIStreamInfoW = record
    fccType,
    fccHandler,
    dwFlags,        // Contains AVITF_* flags
    dwCaps: DWORD;
    wPriority,
    wLanguage: WORD;
    dwScale,
    dwRate, // dwRate / dwScale == samples/second
    dwStart,
    dwLength, // In units above...
    dwInitialFrames,
    dwSuggestedBufferSize,
    dwQuality,
    dwSampleSize: DWORD;
    rcFrame: TRect;
    dwEditCount,
    dwFormatChangeCount: DWORD;
    szName:  array[0..63] of WideChar;
  end;
  TAVIStreamInfo = TAVIStreamInfoW;
  PAVIStreamInfo = ^TAVIStreamInfo;

  PAVIStream = pointer;
  PAVIFile   = pointer;
  TAVIStreamList = array[0..0] of PAVIStream;
  PAVIStreamList = ^TAVIStreamList;
  TAVISaveCallback = function (nPercent: integer): LONG; stdcall;

  TAVICompressOptions = packed record
    fccType     : DWORD;
    fccHandler      : DWORD;
    dwKeyFrameEvery : DWORD;
    dwQuality       : DWORD;
    dwBytesPerSecond    : DWORD;
    dwFlags     : DWORD;
    lpFormat        : pointer;
    cbFormat        : DWORD;
    lpParms     : pointer;
    cbParms     : DWORD;
    dwInterleaveEvery   : DWORD;
  end;
  PAVICompressOptions = ^TAVICompressOptions;

// Palette change data record
const
  RIFF_PaletteChange: DWORD = 1668293411;

type
  TAVIPalChange = packed record
    bFirstEntry     : byte;
    bNumEntries     : byte;
    wFlags      : WORD;
    peNew       : array[byte] of TPaletteEntry;
  end;
  PAVIPalChange = ^TAVIPalChange;

  APAVISTREAM          = array[0..1] of PAVISTREAM;
  APAVICompressOptions = array[0..1] of PAVICompressOptions;


procedure AVIFileInit; stdcall;
procedure AVIFileExit; stdcall;
function AVIFileOpen(var ppfile: PAVIFile; szFile: PChar; uMode: UINT; lpHandler: pointer): HResult; stdcall;
function AVIFileCreateStream(pfile: PAVIFile; var ppavi: PAVISTREAM; var psi: TAVIStreamInfo): HResult; stdcall;
function AVIStreamSetFormat(pavi: PAVIStream; lPos: LONG; lpFormat: pointer; cbFormat: LONG): HResult; stdcall;
function AVIStreamReadFormat(pavi: PAVIStream; lPos: LONG; lpFormat: pointer; var cbFormat: LONG): HResult; stdcall;
function AVIStreamWrite(pavi: PAVIStream; lStart, lSamples: LONG; lpBuffer: pointer; cbBuffer: LONG; dwFlags: DWORD; var plSampWritten: LONG; var plBytesWritten: LONG): HResult; stdcall;
function AVIStreamRelease(pavi: PAVISTREAM): ULONG; stdcall;
function AVIFileRelease(pfile: PAVIFile): ULONG; stdcall;
function AVIFileGetStream(pfile: PAVIFile; var ppavi: PAVISTREAM; fccType: DWORD; lParam: LONG): HResult; stdcall;
function CreateEditableStream(var ppsEditable: PAVISTREAM; psSource: PAVISTREAM): HResult; stdcall;
function AVISaveV(szFile: PChar; pclsidHandler: PCLSID; lpfnCallback: TAVISaveCallback;
  nStreams: integer; pavi: APAVISTREAM; lpOptions: APAVICompressOptions): HResult; stdcall;

const
  AVIERR_OK       = 0;

  AVIIF_LIST      = $01;
  AVIIF_TWOCC     = $02;
  AVIIF_KEYFRAME  = $10;

  streamtypeVIDEO = $73646976; // DWORD( 'v', 'i', 'd', 's' )
  streamtypeAUDIO = $73647561; // DWORD( 'a', 'u', 'd', 's' )


type
  TPixelFormat = (pfDevice, pf1bit, pf4bit, pf8bit, pf15bit, pf16bit, pf24bit, pf32bit, pfCustom);

type
  TAviWriter = class (TComponent)
  private
    TempFileName   : string;
    pFile          : PAVIFile;
    fHeight        : integer;
    fWidth         : integer;
    fStretch       : boolean;
    fFrameTime     : integer;
    fFileName      : string;
    fWavFileName   : string;
    VideoStream    : PAVISTREAM;
    AudioStream    : PAVISTREAM;

    procedure AddVideo;
    procedure AddAudio;
    procedure InternalGetDIBSizes(Bitmap: HBITMAP; var InfoHeaderSize: Integer;
        var ImageSize: longInt; PixelFormat: TPixelFormat);
    function InternalGetDIB(Bitmap: HBITMAP; Palette: HPALETTE;
        var BitmapInfo; var Bits; PixelFormat: TPixelFormat): Boolean;
    procedure InitializeBitmapInfoHeader(Bitmap: HBITMAP; var Info: TBitmapInfoHeader;
           PixelFormat: TPixelFormat);
    procedure SetWavFileName(value : string);

  public
    Bitmaps : TList;
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
    procedure Write;

  published
    property Height   : integer read fHeight  write fHeight;
    property Width    : integer read fWidth   write fWidth;
    property FrameTime: integer read fFrameTime write fFrameTime;
    property Stretch  : boolean read fStretch write fStretch;
    property FileName : string  read fFileName write fFileName;
    property WavFileName  : string  read fWavFileName write SetWavFileName;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure AVIFileInit; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIFileInit';
procedure AVIFileExit; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIFileExit';
function AVIFileOpen; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIFileOpenW';
function AVIFileCreateStream; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIFileCreateStreamW';
function AVIStreamSetFormat; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamSetFormat';
function AVIStreamReadFormat; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamReadFormat';
function AVIStreamWrite; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamWrite';
function AVIStreamRelease; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIStreamRelease';
function AVIFileRelease; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIFileRelease';
function AVIFileGetStream; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIFileGetStream';
function CreateEditableStream; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'CreateEditableStream';
function AVISaveV; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVISaveVW';

constructor TAviWriter.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
    inherited Create(AOwner);
    fHeight    := screen.height div 10;
    fWidth     := screen.width  div 10;
    fFrameTime := 1000;
    fStretch   := true;
    fFileName  := '';
    Bitmaps    := TList.create;
    AVIFileInit;
    TempFileName := {tempdir +} 'temp.avi';
end;

destructor TAviWriter.Destroy;
begin
    Bitmaps.free;
    AviFileExit;
    inherited;
end;

procedure TAviWriter.Write;
var
  ExtBitmap             : TBitmap;
  nstreams              : integer;
  i                     : integer;
  Streams               : APAVISTREAM;
  CompOptions           : APAVICompressOptions;
  AVIERR                : integer;
  refcount              : integer;
begin
   AudioStream := nil;
   VideoStream := nil;

   // If no bitmaps are on the list, raise an error.
   if Bitmaps.count < 1
      then raise Exception.Create('No bitmaps on the Bitmaps list');

   // If anything on the Bitmaps TList is not a bitmap, raise
   // an error.
   for i := 0 to Bitmaps.count - 1 do
   begin
      ExtBitmap := Bitmaps[i];
      if not(ExtBitmap is TBitmap)
         then raise Exception.Create('Bitmaps[' + inttostr(i)
                       + '] is not a TBitmap');
   end; // for

   try
      AddVideo;

      if WavFileName <> ''
         then AddAudio;

      // Create the output file.
      if WavFileName <> ''
         then nstreams := 2
         else nstreams := 1;

      Streams[0] := VideoStream;
      Streams[1] := AudioStream;
      CompOptions[0] := nil;
      CompOptions[1] := nil;

      AVIERR := AVISaveV(
                   pchar(FileName),
                   nil,                    // File handler
                   nil,                    // Callback
                   nStreams,               // Number of streams
                   Streams,
                   CompOptions);           // Compress options for VideoStream
      if AVIERR <> AVIERR_OK then
             raise Exception.Create('Unable to write output file');
   finally
      if assigned(VideoStream)
         then AviStreamRelease(VideoStream);
      if assigned(AudioStream)
         then AviStreamRelease(AudioStream);

      try
         repeat
            refcount := AviFileRelease(pFile);
         until refcount <= 0;
      except
         // ignore exception
      end; // try..except

      DeleteFile(TempFileName);
   end; // try..finally
end;

procedure TAviWriter.AddVideo;
var
  Pstream:         PAVISTREAM;
  StreamInfo:      TAVIStreamInfo;
  BitmapInfo:      PBitmapInfoHeader;
  BitmapInfoSize:  Integer;
  BitmapSize:      longInt;
  BitmapBits:      pointer;
  Bitmap:          TBitmap;
  ExtBitmap:       TBitmap;
  Samples_Written: LONG;
  Bytes_Written:   LONG;
  AVIERR:          integer;
  i:               integer;
  ok: Int64;
  mode: uInt32;
  fn: pChar;
  err: string;
begin
    // Open AVI file for write
    pfile := nil;
    mode  := OF_CREATE or OF_WRITE or OF_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE;
    fn    := pchar (TempFileName);

    ok := AVIFileOpen (pFile, fn, mode, nil);
    if ok = AVIERR_BADFORMAT    then err := 'The file could not be read, indicating a corrupt file or an unrecognized format.';
    if ok = AVIERR_MEMORY       then err := 'The file could not be opened because of insufficient memory.';
    if ok = AVIERR_FILEREAD     then err := 'A disk error occurred while reading the file.';
    if ok = AVIERR_FILEOPEN     then err := 'A disk error occurred while opening the file.';
    if ok = REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG then err := 'According to the registry, the type of file specified in AVIFileOpen does not have a handler to process it.';
    if err <> '' then raise Exception.Create (err);

    // Allocate the bitmap to which the bitmaps on the Bitmaps Tlist
    // will be copied.
    Bitmap        := TBitmap.create;
    Bitmap.Height := self.Height;
    Bitmap.Width  := self.Width;

    // Write the stream header.
    try
       FillChar (StreamInfo, sizeof (StreamInfo), 0);

       // Set frame rate and scale
       StreamInfo.dwRate  := 1000;
       StreamInfo.dwScale := fFrameTime;
       StreamInfo.fccType := streamtypeVIDEO;
       StreamInfo.fccHandler := 0;
       StreamInfo.dwFlags := 0;
       StreamInfo.dwSuggestedBufferSize := 0;
       StreamInfo.rcFrame.Right  := self.width;
       StreamInfo.rcFrame.Bottom := self.height;

       // Open AVI data stream
       if (AVIFileCreateStream(pFile, pStream, StreamInfo) <> AVIERR_OK) then
           raise Exception.Create('Failed to create AVI video stream');

       try
          // Write the bitmaps to the stream.
          for i := 0 to Bitmaps.count - 1 do
          begin
             BitmapInfo := nil;
             BitmapBits := nil;
             try

               // Copy the bitmap from the list to the AVI bitmap,
               // stretching if desired. If the caller elects not to
               // stretch, use the first pixel in the bitmap as a
               // background color in case either the height or
               // width of the source is smaller than the output.
               // If Draw fails, do a StretchDraw.
               ExtBitmap := Bitmaps[i];
               if fStretch
                  then Bitmap.Canvas.StretchDraw
                           (Rect(0,0,self.width,self.height),ExtBitmap)
                  else try
                         with Bitmap.Canvas do begin
                            Brush.Color := ExtBitmap.Canvas.Pixels[0,0];
                            Brush.Style := bsSolid;
                            FillRect(Rect(0,0,Bitmap.Width,Bitmap.Height));
                            Draw(0,0,ExtBitmap);
                         end;
                       except
                         Bitmap.Canvas.StretchDraw
                            (Rect(0,0,self.width,self.height),ExtBitmap);
                       end;

               // Determine size of DIB
               InternalGetDIBSizes(Bitmap.Handle, BitmapInfoSize, BitmapSize, pf8bit);
               if (BitmapInfoSize = 0) then
                  raise Exception.Create('Failed to retrieve bitmap info');

               // Get DIB header and pixel buffers
               GetMem(BitmapInfo, BitmapInfoSize);
               GetMem(BitmapBits, BitmapSize);
               InternalGetDIB
                     (Bitmap.Handle, 0, BitmapInfo^, BitmapBits^, pf8bit);

               // On the first time through, set the stream format.
               if i = 0 then
                  if (AVIStreamSetFormat(pStream, 0, BitmapInfo, BitmapInfoSize) <> AVIERR_OK) then
                      raise Exception.Create('Failed to set AVI stream format');

               // Write frame to the video stream
               AVIERR :=
                  AVIStreamWrite(pStream, i, 1, BitmapBits, BitmapSize, AVIIF_KEYFRAME,
                             Samples_Written, Bytes_Written);
               if AVIERR <> AVIERR_OK then
                    raise Exception.Create
                            ('Failed to add frame to AVI. Err='
                               + inttohex(AVIERR,8));
             finally
               if (BitmapInfo <> nil) then
                 FreeMem(BitmapInfo);
               if (BitmapBits <> nil) then
                 FreeMem(BitmapBits);
             end;
          end;

          // Create the editable VideoStream from pStream.
          if CreateEditableStream(VideoStream,pStream) <> AVIERR_OK then
                    raise Exception.Create
                            ('Could not create Video Stream');
       finally
          AviStreamRelease(pStream);
       end;

    finally
      Bitmap.free;
    end;
end;

procedure TAviWriter.AddAudio;
var
   InputFile    : PAVIFILE;
   InputStream  : PAVIStream;
   err: string;
   ok: Int64;
begin
   // Open the audio file.
    ok := AVIFileOpen(InputFile, pchar(WavFileName),OF_READ, nil);
    if ok = AVIERR_BADFORMAT    then err := 'The file could not be read, indicating a corrupt file or an unrecognized format.';
    if ok = AVIERR_MEMORY       then err := 'The file could not be opened because of insufficient memory.';
    if ok = AVIERR_FILEREAD     then err := 'A disk error occurred while reading the file.';
    if ok = AVIERR_FILEOPEN     then err := 'A disk error occurred while opening the file.';
    if ok = REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG then err := 'According to the registry, the type of file specified in AVIFileOpen does not have a handler to process it.';
    if err <> '' then raise Exception.Create (err);

   // Open the audio stream.
   try
     if (AVIFileGetStream(InputFile, InputStream, 0, 0) <> AVIERR_OK) then
         raise Exception.Create('Unable to get audio stream');

     try
       // Create AudioStream as a copy of InputStream
       if (CreateEditableStream(AudioStream,InputStream) <> AVIERR_OK) then
            raise Exception.Create('Failed to create editable AVI audio stream');
     finally
       AviStreamRelease(InputStream);
     end;

   finally
     AviFileRelease(InputFile);
   end;
end;

// --------------
// InternalGetDIB
// --------------
// Converts a bitmap to a DIB of a specified PixelFormat.
//
// Note: The InternalGetDIBSizes function can be used to calculate the
// nescessary sizes of the BitmapInfo and Bits buffers.
//
// From graphics.pas, "optimized" for our use

function TAviWriter.InternalGetDIB
(
   Bitmap: HBITMAP;   // The handle of the source bitmap
   Palette: HPALETTE; // The handle of the source palette
   var BitmapInfo;    // The buffer that will receive the DIB's TBitmapInfo structure.
                      // A buffer of sufficient size must have been allocated prior to
                      // calling this function
   var Bits;          // The buffer that will receive the DIB's pixel data
   PixelFormat: TPixelFormat // The pixel format of the destination DIB
): Boolean; // True on success, False on failure
var
  OldPal    : HPALETTE;
  DC        : HDC;
begin
  InitializeBitmapInfoHeader(Bitmap, TBitmapInfoHeader(BitmapInfo), PixelFormat);
  OldPal := 0;
  DC := CreateCompatibleDC(0);
  try
    if (Palette <> 0) then
    begin
      OldPal := SelectPalette(DC, Palette, False);
      RealizePalette(DC);
    end;
    Result := (GetDIBits(DC, Bitmap, 0, abs(TBitmapInfoHeader(BitmapInfo).biHeight),
      @Bits, TBitmapInfo(BitmapInfo), DIB_RGB_COLORS) <> 0);
  finally
    if (OldPal <> 0) then
      SelectPalette(DC, OldPal, False);
    DeleteDC(DC);
  end;
end;


// -------------------
// InternalGetDIBSizes
// -------------------
// Calculates the buffer sizes nescessary for convertion of a bitmap to a DIB
// of a specified PixelFormat.
// See the GetDIBSizes API function for more info.
// From graphics.pas, "optimized" for our use

procedure TAviWriter.InternalGetDIBSizes
(
   Bitmap: HBITMAP;             // The handle of the source bitmap
   var InfoHeaderSize: Integer; // The returned size of a buffer that will receive
                                // the DIB's TBitmapInfo structure
   var ImageSize: longInt;      // The returned size of a buffer that will receive the DIB's pixel data
   PixelFormat: TPixelFormat    // The pixel format of the destination DIB
);
var
  Info: TBitmapInfoHeader;
begin
  InitializeBitmapInfoHeader(Bitmap, Info, PixelFormat);
  // Check for palette device format
  if (Info.biBitCount > 8) then
  begin
    // Header but no palette
    InfoHeaderSize := SizeOf(TBitmapInfoHeader);
    if ((Info.biCompression and BI_BITFIELDS) <> 0) then
      Inc(InfoHeaderSize, 12);
  end else
    // Header and palette
    InfoHeaderSize := SizeOf(TBitmapInfoHeader) + SizeOf(TRGBQuad) * (1 shl Info.biBitCount);
  ImageSize := Info.biSizeImage;
end;

// --------------------------
// InitializeBitmapInfoHeader
// --------------------------
// Fills a TBitmapInfoHeader with the values of a bitmap when converted to a
// DIB of a specified PixelFormat.
// From graphics.pas, "optimized" for our use

procedure TAviWriter.InitializeBitmapInfoHeader
(
   Bitmap: HBITMAP;              // The handle of the source bitmap
   var Info: TBitmapInfoHeader;  // The TBitmapInfoHeader buffer that will receive the values
   PixelFormat: TPixelFormat     // The pixel format of the destination DIB
);
var
  DIB       : TDIBSection;
  Bytes     : Integer;
  function AlignBit(Bits, BitsPerPixel, Alignment: Cardinal): Cardinal;
  begin
    Dec(Alignment);
    Result := ((Bits * BitsPerPixel) + Alignment) and not Alignment;
    Result := Result SHR 3;
  end;
begin
  DIB.dsbmih.biSize := 0;
  Bytes := GetObject(Bitmap, SizeOf(DIB), @DIB);
  if (Bytes = 0) then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid bitmap');
//    Error(sInvalidBitmap);

  if (Bytes >= (sizeof(DIB.dsbm) + sizeof(DIB.dsbmih))) and
    (DIB.dsbmih.biSize >= sizeof(DIB.dsbmih)) then
    Info := DIB.dsbmih
  else
  begin
    FillChar(Info, sizeof(Info), 0);
    with Info, DIB.dsbm do
    begin
      biSize := SizeOf(Info);
      biWidth := bmWidth;
      biHeight := bmHeight;
    end;
  end;
  case PixelFormat of
    pf1bit: Info.biBitCount := 1;
    pf4bit: Info.biBitCount := 4;
    pf8bit: Info.biBitCount := 8;
    pf24bit: Info.biBitCount := 24;
  else
//    Error(sInvalidPixelFormat);
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid pixel format');
    // Info.biBitCount := DIB.dsbm.bmBitsPixel * DIB.dsbm.bmPlanes;
  end;
  Info.biPlanes := 1;
  Info.biCompression := BI_RGB; // Always return data in RGB format
  Info.biSizeImage := AlignBit(Info.biWidth, Info.biBitCount, 32) * Cardinal(abs(Info.biHeight));
end;

procedure TAviWriter.SetWavFileName(value : string);
begin
   if lowercase(fWavFileName) <> lowercase(value)
      then if lowercase(ExtractFileExt(value)) <> '.wav'
             then raise Exception.Create('WavFileName must name a file '
                             + 'with the .wav extension')
             else fWavFileName := value;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TAviWriter]);
end;

end.
```

Comment: They are from AviFil32, I added the headers to the code example. As the code is rather old I presume they don't refer to unicode. Should I replace `procedure AVIFileInit; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIFileInit'` by `procedure AVIFileInit; stdcall; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVIFileInitW'`?

Comment: Did what you adviced and AddVideo works!. Are now trying to understand what happens in AVIsaveV. Does the same kind of advice apply to that function?

Comment: Nope, only those which end with the `A` char, but you should verify it according to MSDN reference. For instance if you look at the [`AVIFileOpen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then you can see in the bottom of the page the `Unicode and ANSI names` section and this section is available only for the functions which have ANSI and Unicode versions.

Comment: @TLama, its [*the codez form the internetz*](http://www.bottledlight.com/mappy/source/sysAviWriter.pas). And probably copyvio too.

Comment: @TLama, All the AviWriters just subtly differ. I also tried the one you found at Koders, has the advantage of having codecs. But they all refer to AviFileOpenA, which I changed to W. I set `TAVIStreamInfo` pointing to `TAVIStreamInfoW` and that is the only structure I can see with an A suffix. But I am really curious now: did anyone ever get this working in Unicode or XE?

Comment: I've got code that creates AVI files using those functions so it can be done.

Comment: The major problem is that we can't see your current code of the `TAviWriter` class and the headers you are trying to convert from ANSI to Unicode. I think, it might be ok, to post it to the [`code review`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Anyway, let's clean up the conversation here for further discussions. At this time we know the problem is caused by the non Unicode version of headers called from the Unicode version of Delphi.

Comment: @Tlama, I was not aware of that facility. I have posted the code (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9860/how-to-adjust-taviwriter-to-unicode) I posted the code I originally downloaded, not the code you found which incidentally generates the same error. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: If there is a note `Unicode and ANSI names` in the function's [`reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756818%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then it means you have to choose one of the names, either the `A` ended or `W` ended version, the base name of the function (without `A` nor `W`) doesn't physically exists, it's just being referred to the one of the versions depending if the compiler uses Unicode or not.

Comment: this is nice , but i'm not getting sound when i set `WavFileName` does the audio work in this solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the import part of the [`AVISaveV`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756818%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to the Unicode version of it. When the function in the Windows API reference has the note `Unicode and ANSI names` it means for you, in Delphi, you have to choose either from the Unicode version of the function or from the ANSI one depending on what compiler will you use.

You're trying to call the `AVISaveV`, which physically doesn't exists. There's only `AVISaveVA` and the `AVISaveVW` in `avifil32.dll` and since you want to convert this code to Unicode, try to change the function import this way:

```
function AVISaveV; external 'avifil32.dll' name 'AVISaveVW';
```

[image]

This is just a first thought, the code with the definition like was cannot work even in non Unicode versions of Delphi, because it called the not existing function.

Answer (score 13):

There's actually a really easy way to do this using ffmpeg without any code at all. Simply name all your image files something like:

```
image-0001.png
```

Then use ffmpeg to bundle them up into a video:

```
ffmpeg -i 'img-%04d.png' -r 10 out.avi
```

(`-r` is the output frame rate.)

Comment: This might be a possibility, but requires I run an extra program from my program which is not what I want.

Comment: If you don't want to run it (which would probably be a quick solution to your problem) then you may consider to find an ffmpeg dll and invoke it via a library call.

Comment: The link in my question points to a solution for FFMpeg in Delphi. I could not get that working, which is the reason I moved to AviWriter which now works (see code).

Answer (score 3):

I have used Mitov's video library with great success on tasks like the one you describe. It's free for non-commercial use, and you can download a copy to play with. And, it's amazingly fast. If you're on an Intel chip, it uses the Intel IPP library to squeeze the most out of whatever your CPU architecture is. http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp/#support

I'm continually blown away by the power of this multi-tasking library.  I've posted about it before, and it may seem like I'm a paid employee for them, but I'm not. I'm just astonished at how lucky (yes, lucky) I was to select this library for a major project. It's never let me down. 
Some things are worth paying for, and the Mitov libraries are one of them. Good code, frequent updates, and rapid support right from the developers when necessary.

Be sure to check out Mitov's sample programs, while will give you a good idea of how it works.

Here's the site: [www.mitov.com](http://www.mitov.com)

Sorry I don't have any source I can share.

Comment: This looks interesting, I will check this out. Thanks.